# How does one identify if the ML model is overfitting the dataset or not?

Tags: python, machine-learning, machine-learning-model

I have been comparing different regression models from sklearn, On doing so I was confused with the model's score value that i got.
Below in the code you can see that i have used both Linear Regression and Ridge Regression but the difference in score values for the training and test data set vary by a lot.

```
using Linear Regression

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression as lr
model = lr()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
model.predict(X_test)
print("LINEAR REGRESSION")
print("Training Score", end = "\t")
print(model.score(X_train, y_train))
print("Test Score", end = "\t")
print(model.score(X_test, y_test))

------------------------------------------------------------
O/P
LINEAR REGRESSION
Training Score  0.7147120015665793
Test Score  0.4242120003778227


Using Ridge Regression

from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge as r
model = r(alpha = 20).fit(X_train, y_train)
model.predict(X_test)
print("RIDGE REGRESSION")
print("Training Score", end = "\t")
print(model.score(X_train, y_train))
print("Test Score", end = "\t")
print(model.score(X_test, y_test))

-----------------------------------------------------------
O/P
RIDGE REGRESSION
Training Score  0.4991610348613835
Test Score  0.32642156452579363
```

My question is, Does a smaller difference between the score values of the training and test dataset mean that my model is Generalized and fitting equally for both the test and Train Data ( not overfitting ) or does it mean something else.
If it does mean something else please do explain.

And How does the "alpha" value affect the ridge regression model? 
I am a beginner so please do explain anything as simple as possible.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add a separate validation set to you `model.fit` or you set the `validation_split` paramter like in the [keras docs of the fit method](https://keras.io/models/model/), I don't know if there is something like that in sklearn kit.

But in general the scores for the validation-set or test-st and the training set should be nearly equal, otherwise the model tends to overfitting.

Also there are a bunch of metrics you can use to evaluate your model. I would recommend the [book Oreilly Deep Learning Page 39](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/deep-learning/9781491924570/). There is a really good explanation.

Or have a look [here](https://medium.com/@rossbulat/precision-and-recall-how-its-used-in-deep-learning-a252d03ed792) and [here](https://medium.com/greyatom/what-is-underfitting-and-overfitting-in-machine-learning-and-how-to-deal-with-it-6803a989c76).

Or look [here chapter 5.2](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/ml.html).

Feel free to ask other questions.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Max's answer, overfitting is a modelling error when the trained model models the trained data too well. Now this usually occurs when the model is complex enough (high VC dimension) that it learns very intricate details and noises that it will negatively impact the final performance. [VC Dimension](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/182685/why-is-vc-dimension-important) [Caltech Lecture on VC Overfitting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EQWr3GGCdzw) A simple way to observe overfitting is to look at the difference between the training and test results.

Going back to your example, the score difference between test and training data for linear regression is 0.290. While the difference for ridge regression is 0.179. From this single experiment alone, it is difficult to judge whether or not a model is overfitting since usually in practice there will always be some difference. But here, we can say that ridge regression tends to less overfit for this dataset.

Now when making a decision on which model to pick, we have to also consider other factors beside overfitting itself. In this case Linear Regression tends to perform 10% higher on the test dataset as compared to Ridge Regression, so you have to take that into account as well. Perhaps conducting further experiment using different validation techniques and fine tune different hyper-parameters should be the next steps.